# How do I console.log the content of a response?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have the following in `vehicle.service.ts`:

```
getVehicleById(id: number): Observable<Vehicle> {

const url = `${this.vehicleUrl}?vehicleId=${id}`;

console.log(`GET vehicle details url: ${url}`);

return this.http.get<Vehicle>(url).pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log(`getVehicleById(): fetched vehicle id = ${id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Vehicle>(`vehicle id = ${id}`))
);
}
```

The console output in .tap() is written. The .handleError() is not hit - this is good as it tells me the service call was successful.

The problem is my component HTML is not populated with the JSON returned from the service call. How do I output the results of the GET request so I can see what I'm actually getting back from the service. I pasted the value of `url` into Postman and I get the expected results so it's gotta be something in the angular project. I just need to figure out what is wrong and verifying the data from the service seems like a good place to start.

How do I output the results of the GET request to console.log()?

Comment: `console.log`s aren't populated into the html. You can see its output in the DevTools of your browser.

Comment: @Batajus - I understand that. The HTML component is not being populated with the content from the service call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the console log in your subscribe to log the JSON data being returned from the service.

In the component calling the service you should have something like this.

```
this.vehicleService.getVehicleById(1).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: The log messages I expect to see are present but I also want to see the JSON content returned from the service.

Comment: The `console.log(...)` in the `subscribe` method should write out the json data. If you want to see the raw data, check the `Network` tab in chrome. You can look at the response from the request to see what's being returned.

Comment: Network tab contained the response body but I did not check it initially. Thanks for the reminder! I added the above to .subscribe() and I'm able to log the response body to the console.